# Including a non-python file in a module required by cx_freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, python-module

I'm trying to generate a .exe for my python project. Opening the generated .exe gives me an error, this is because my included module `wordcloud` is trying to open a file that's usually right next to its source code

The module on its own looks like this (as found in `C:/python/Lib/site-packages/wordcloud`):

```
__init__.py
__pycache__/
color_from_image.py
DroidSansMono.ttf
query_integral_image.pyd
stopwords
wordcloud.py
wordcloud_cli.py
```

The module inside the generated cx_freeze exe looks like this (as found in `C:/.../my-application/builds/0.1/my-app/my-app.exe/wordcloud`):

```
color_from_image.pyc
query_integral_image.pyc
wordcloud.pyc
__init__.pyc
```

If you did not know it, cx_freeze includes all modules inside the .exe itself, the generated .exe is both an executable file as well as an archive.

In this generatec exe/archive, I'd like to add the `stopwords` file that is found within the original source. Is this possible?

The big difference between this question and cx_freeze's `include_files` option is that the files shouldn't end up in the resulting folder, but in the resulting .exe file, right next to the wordcloud dependency!

Edit: I tried to use `include_files` with the .exe as the path, but as I expected this does not work.

`error: build\exe.win32-3.3\my-app.exe: Cannot create a file when that file already exists`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using the `include_zip` option.

in setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

zip_includes = [
    (r'C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\wordcloud\stopwords', 'wordcloud/stopwords'),
    (r'C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\wordcloud\DroidSansMono.ttf', 'wordcloud/DroidSansMono.ttf')
]

setup(  name = "my-app",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "my-app description",
        options = {"build_exe": {"zip_includes": zip_includes}},
        executables = [Executable("entry.py", base=base)])
```

Too bad that this still didn't end up solving the issue, since the required module is using `open('.../archived-file.exe/wordcloud/stopwords')` to read the file, `open` doesn't support reading from archived files.

Comment: As for zip file you may find this useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: @shuttle87 The code calling `open` is not mine, I'll have to replace the dependency with my own, or patch it during build :/